# Vagrant installation issue

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to install Open edx Devstack on Ubuntu 16.04. I am asked to do below cmd:

```
vagrant box add {BOX-NAME} {BOX-FILE}
```

that means

```
vagrant box add ginkgo-devstack-2017-07-14 /home/millionlights/vagrant-images_ginkgo-devstack-2017-07-14.box
```

but after this it shows:

> The program 'vagrant' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install vagrant

And when I run `sudo apt install vagrant` it shows

```
vagrant is already the newest version (1:2.0.3)
```

Also when I do `vagrant --version`  it shows:

> The program 'vagrant' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install vagrant

This is contradictory behavior, I am confused if vagrant is installed or not ???